# Model which achieves good results on the Adult dataset, especially on the minority class

Tags: machine-learning, classification, random-forest, data-preprocessing, adaboost

I'm looking for a model which achieves an high prediction and recall on the [Adult](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/adult) dataset. I've tried with random forests, but couldn't get a model with good results on the minority class. Here are my results:

```
precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.88      0.94      0.91      5432
           1       0.79      0.62      0.69      1802

    accuracy                           0.86      7234
   macro avg       0.83      0.78      0.80      7234
weighted avg       0.86      0.86      0.86      7234
```

Has any of you ever achieved better results on Adult, especially on the minority class?

I'm working on my thesis on Membership Inference Attacks, which work well on models who are  slightly overfitted. Any suggestion on how can I reach better results? I've tried with neural networks (3/4 layers) (which aren't great for this kind of tabular datasets), Adaboost (with results similar to the random forest) and random forests.

The preprocessing I applied on adult is target encoding on the categorical variables, deletion of duplicates/missing values, and Standard scaling.

In [this notebook](https://github.com/gerzin/mlem/blob/main/notebooks/datasets/adult/BB_NO_CLUSTERING/AdultBlackboxWithoutClustering.ipynb) there are my best achievements on the classification of Adult (first 20 cells), but I need way better results on the minority class in order to get good results in the membership inference attack.

Comment: Is there any website with a collection of known datasets and corresponding models, with the respective results?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated. OpenML features this data set as well as several tasks for which people have tried their luck. Have a look [here](https://www.openml.org/search?type=task&id=7287)